# Bug in ggplot2 labs function? Labelling the x-axis doesn't function

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the first time I come across R refusing to rename the label of the x-axis when using ggplot2. When using the code below the x-axis label remains 'spending' (as is a variable in the dataframe), whereas I want to change the label into 'Opinion on College Student Budget'.

```
spending <- as.factor(c("Increase", "Decrease", "Same", "NoAnswer"))
frequency <- c(0.44, 0.16, 0.37, 0.03)
budget <- data.frame(spending, frequency)

budgetBar <- ggplot(budget, aes(spending, frequency))
budgetBar + geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete("spending", limits = c("Increase", "Same", "Decrease", "NoAnswer")) + 
  labs(x = "Opinion on College Student Budget", y = "Percentage") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Is this a bug or something in my code that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Use `scale_x_discrete("Opinion on College Student Budget", ..)`

Comment: To exposit on @GGamba's comment answer: the `name` param/value in `scale_x_discrete()` overrides what you set in `labs(x=...)`. Pick one or the other, not both. Also, consider either using consistent named params or no named params and whitespace is free in most editors (carriage returns are your BFF)

Comment: I see! Thank you GGamba for the solution and hrbrmstr for the elaboration and advice ;)